# how to get span class value from gridview column in razor and want to show this span class value in textbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

```
grid.Column(columnName: "groupName", header: "Group Name", style: "HD-td-width-col", 
format:span class="@item.groupId  groupname">@item.groupName /span),
```

I am using java-script but i am not getting span class value.......

Answer (score 0):

You're missing some `<` and `>` in your code. Try the following code instead.

```
grid.Column(
    columnName: "groupName", 
    header: "Group Name", 
    style: "HD-td-width-col", 
    format: @<text>
                 <span class="@item.groupId  groupname">@item.groupName</span>
             </text>),
```

Comment: I'm glad it works for you. Please don't forget to mark my answer as correct if you're happy with it.